# Outlook add-in on owa mobile: body.getAsync do not get all the body message

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I write an outlook add-in in js and now I try to customize it to mobile version ( OWA app and browsers).

In OWA app read mode - If the message is bigger then 50,000 characters the getAsync return just part of the message and not all the message.
It returns something like the first 47,000 characters.
I don't find any reason for it because in rich client and Outlook web 365 I get the all message.

The code i used:

```
var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        item.body.getAsync(
            typeOfGet,
             { asyncContext: "This is passed to the callback" },
                 function callback(resultbody) {
                 // the resultbody.value is the message but i get just part of it
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm whether you are using Outlook App or Mobile browser? If Outlook App, Android or iOS?

Comment: I used 2 mobile apps: The first is called "Outlook" and everything work great there. The second is called "Outlook Mobile" and there i get the problem. On mobile browser (i used chrome) there is the same problem and on PC browser (chrome) in mobile mode i get the same problem as well .

Comment: Okay, The second app "Outlook Mobile" is it "OWA for Android"? because I am not able to find "Outlook Mobile" app link. Please comment link of that app.

Comment: Yes it is OWA for android : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.exchange.mowa            thank You